# i want to create a filter api with elasticsaerch while user select an item then full string macthing result must be return

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp

Requirment is : 1. return all of the available university .
2. when user wants to filter the result and  select an university then user will get only one university details what he select.
like: there have available uniserity is "A E T School Of Nursing OppSuresh Petrol Bunk MCRoad","A E C S Maaruti School Of Nursing". if user select one then it should be return. but as of now if i select one i got both of them.

here is my analyzer

```
"analysis":{
   "filter":{
      "long_suffixes":{
         "type":"edgeNGram",
         "min_gram":3,
         "max_gram":20
      }
   },
   "analyzer":{
      "keyword_analyzer":{
         "type":"custom",
         "tokenizer":"keyword",
         "filter":[
            "lowercase",
            "suffixes",
            "kstem"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I have index two items.

```
POST university/_doc/1
{
   "name":"A E C S Maaruti School Of Nursing"
}


POST university/_doc/2   
{       
   name: "A E T School Of Nursing OppSuresh Petrol Bunk MCRoad"   
}
```

Here is my query

```
GET university/_search  
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "multi_match":{
               "query":"A E C S Maaruti School Of Nursing",
               "fields":[
                  "name"
               ],
               "type":"phrase",
               "analyzer":"long_keyword_analyzer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

while I'm passing "A E C S Maaruti School Of Nursing" this university name.
my expected result is "{id: 1, name: "A E C S Maaruti School Of Nursing"}".

but I got both of them. I think in the same item "A E" this character is matching. so how can I ignore this type of match when I want to filter?

Comment: provide your mapping and the analyzer long_keyword_analyzer.